# Unable to access SAMBA shares via Windows 7 (The network path was not found)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, samba

I have a samba share setup in Ubuntu that i'm able to access via boxee perfectly. In windows 7 starter, it recognizes the share folder (TUX) after configuring the workgroup to be the same.

However, it is not asking for username/password and keeps saying "Error code: 0x80070035. The network path was not found"

How do I force windows to ask me for username and password? Also, my smbtree in Ubuntu shows the following:

```
MSHOME
    \\TUX                   tux server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        \\TUX\IPC$              IPC Service (tux server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        \\TUX\xyx masked download   
        \\TUX\vuze downloads    VUZE
        \\TUX\print$            Printer Drivers
```

Not sure why there are 2 levels inside MSHOME and could be causing the issue too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try map the path as a network and select to specify your own username and password, this can be done from My Computer (or just Computer in Windows 7).

[image]

Comment: already tried that...tried with "Connect using different credentials" checked, but still same error. Also able to ping 192.168.1.100 properly, but it is just not asking for authentication information

Comment: @zooter try map ```\\TUX\vuze downloads ``` and not just ```\\TUX``` ?

Comment: addendum...I ping TUX and that was mapped to 192.168.1.100 -- so I used the same as given above (map) and tried to connect to \\tux\vuze and it asked for username and password this time, but even after giving correct login it failed. Then I refrshed and viola, the drives were available. strange that IP is not working but name is working!

Comment: ok just as an additional detail, there is something wrong with the configuration in Ubuntu samba...the correct way to get this mapping working in Windows is to try and map \\tux\tux (which will then give list of folders that are being shared

Comment: @zooter glad you got it sorted! Dont know much about ubuntu so i cant help there :)